# magento2 how to order email template in order id pass in anchor tag

Tags: magento2.3.2, order-email

I want to **dynamic order id** pass in *anchor tag*

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{trans 'To make changes to your order, you can  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxxxxxx&text=Order %23%increment_id%0AHello, Magento. I have an order and would need some assistance with it.">whatsapp us</a>' with your order number
        increment_id=| raw after 123}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**and whatsapp link text like**

> Order ###### ​
>  ​Hello, Magento. I have an order and would need some
>   assistance with it

how can achieve that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your src link in <a> tag has whitespaces, did you tried to Url encode?

Comment: @Piyush yes i have try that

Comment: Then I would suggest to divide your text in separate {{trans "" }}, Or you can set this text as var before sending to email template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{trans 'To make changes to your order, you can  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxxxxxxxxx&text=My order:%increment_id and i want to change">whatsapp us</a>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: not working Man!!  https://prnt.sc/q9ndss also link is not working

Comment: Which link generates on "whatsapp us" if you click?

Comment: Yes correct but i have same code yesterday try that still problem is coming %increment_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`$order.increment_id`** for order id.